# r taking last and first non NA elements from vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I have a data frame

```
a = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,40,32,46,98,900,NA,NA,78,87,43,78,NA,NA,NA)
b = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
d = cbind(a,b)
```

I want to get part of this data from the first non NA element to the last one.Tha results should be:

```
40 32 46 98 900 NA Na 78 87 43 78
6   7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16
```

How should I solve my problem?

Comment: `zoo::na.trim(d)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `na.trim` function from `zoo` package

```
> zoo::na.trim(d)

    a  b
6   40  6
7   32  7
8   46  8
9   98  9
10 900 10
11  NA 11
12  NA 12
13  78 13
14  87 14
15  43 15
16  78 16
```

**Note**- You can also look for `sides` argument of `na.trim` function for more alteration.

Answer (score 0):

One `base R` possibility could be:

```
d[rev(cumsum(rev(!is.na(a)))) != 0 & cumsum(!is.na(a)) != 0, ]

        a  b
 [1,]  40  6
 [2,]  32  7
 [3,]  46  8
 [4,]  98  9
 [5,] 900 10
 [6,]  NA 11
 [7,]  NA 12
 [8,]  78 13
 [9,]  87 14
[10,]  43 15
[11,]  78 16
```

In individual steps:

```
rev(cumsum(rev(!is.na(a))))

 [1] 9 9 9 9 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 4 4 3 2 1 0 0 0

cumsum(!is.na(a))

 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 5 5 6 7 8 9 9 9 9

rev(cumsum(rev(!is.na(a)))) != 0 & cumsum(!is.na(a)) != 0

 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[14]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```